# Join JSON Objects as one

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have multiple JSON objects and I want to combine them into one bigger JSON Object and then only pass this JSON object to a server. How would I go about doing this? Also, how would I then extract those objects from the server side using C#?

This is what I have right now.

```
    var newBillerJSON = this.ConvertListToJSON(newBillerResults);
    var benchJSON = this.ConvertListToJSON(benchResults);
    var sixtyDayJSON = this.ConvertListToJSON(sixtyDayResults);
    var unassignedJSON = this.ConvertListToJSON(unassignedResults);
    var totalSummaryJSON = this.ConvertListToJSON(countResults);
```

Each of these contains the individual JSON Object, created from `this.ConvertListToJSON()`

Can I combine these into one JSON object? When the server reads this object, how would I then extract those JSON objects from it?

This is an example of what one JSON object looks like

```
{
  "TotalSummaryCounts": [
    {
      "BenchHours": "1316",
      "EffectiveBench": "29",
      "Contributors": "37",
      "FourtyHourContributors": "14",
      "AvailableBench": "26",
      "EffectiveBillers": "79.533333"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Combine the objects before you convert them to json?

Comment: If I combine the objects before I convert them, won't I lose the ability to tell where one object ends and another begins?

Comment: You want to aim for a structure like: `{"TotalSummaryCounts" : [{},{}], "unassigned" : [{},{},{}]` so that each of the original objects is a key in the new object you create.